# How to correctly build code for gcc with netapi32?

Tags: c, gcc, netapi32

I just try build [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum) for GCC.

But I got several problems.

My system is:

- Win10
- msys64 with ucrt64 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
- `c:\windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.2486.1.5\amd64_microsoft-windows-netapi32_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.2130_none_0202483cb6bb2fc6\f\netapi32.dll`
- Atom as IDE (I have not VS)
- `cmd` as console

I try: `gcc main.c -o main.exe -lnetapi32`

But `gcc` returned:

> undefined reference to `WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

OK - wrong entry point.
Changed `wMain` in `WinMain`.
Result:

```
main.c:11:5: error: conflicting types for 'WinMain'; have 'int(int,  wchar_t **)' {aka 'int(int,  short unsigned int **)'}
   11 | int WinMain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
      |     ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/windows.h:70,
                 from main.c:8:
c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/winbase.h:1128:14: note: previous declaration of 'WinMain' with type 'int(struct HINSTANCE__ *, struct HINSTANCE__ *, CHAR *, int)' {aka 'int(struct HINSTANCE__ *, struct HINSTANCE__ *, char *, int)'}
 1128 |   int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wmain` is an extension by Microsoft, and insofar I know not supported by gcc. You need to change the entry function to a standard `int main(int argc, char **args)`. You can also use `WinMain` but then you'll have to use `int WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)`

Comment: Thank! it compiled successfuly with int main(int argc, char **argv) and int WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)

Comment: but i have new problem with netapi32. My main.exe tould me that netapi32.dll 
Not intended to run on Windows or contains an error. Error status 0xc0000130
Can I really run this code? I built and tried to run the code under admin. The effect is the same.

Comment: That usually has to do with a wrong version. Try updating, rebooting, and if that doesn't work try re-registering the dll.